# Empty Response only on HTTPS, only with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, https

For the last few months we've has a client site working fine over HTTPS and HTTP, however as of a week or two ago we've had intermittent reports of it failing in Google Chrome.

As of last week I also got the issue, which is Chrome claiming `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` to all requests sent through HTTPS.

This isn't replicated in any other browsers and the `Security` tab of the inspector declares the certificate valid and all page resources secure.

Anyone got some suggestions? I'm at a loss as to what to do, it feels like it might be a browser bug itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Originally provided by a user called @daFlame, but it then got deleted within a few hours?]*

The issue is caused by Chrome struggling with the cipher suites cPanel uses by default. CPanel are aware of the issue, and I've reported a ticket to Chrome.

CPanel's work around can be found [here](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/https-chrome-os-problem.605319/#post-2454643), but I'll provide a summary:

Go to `WHM >> Service Configuration >> Apache Configuration >> Global Configuration`

Then find the value `SSL Cipher Suite` and change it from the default to:

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS`
```

Once Apache is rebuilt, the errors stop.